# Error when selecting from two tables and performing an inner join on another

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    table_comments1.*, table_comments2.* 
FROM 
    [table_comments1], [table_comments2]
INNER JOIN  
    [users] ON [table_comments1].fk_user_id = [users].user_id 
            AND [table_comments2].fk_user_id = [users].user_id
ORDER BY 
    comment_date DESC
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm getting this error:

> The multi-part identifier "table_comments1.fk_user_id" could not be bound.

I want to end up sorting all comments from both tables by datetime, but got that problem.

Comment: Using comma-style cross joins is generally considered bad practice, and I worry about either the naming or use of these tables. But that all said, this specific error just means there is no `fk_user_id` column in the `table_comments1` table. Double-check your schema, and try a simpler query, without the cross join.

Comment: Hmm I didn't realize that two joins could be made in the same select statement... interesting.

Comment: Learn to use SQL 92 joins (`INNER JOIN`). Do not use comma style joins. The only thing worse than using comma style joins is mixing the two types. Your error simply means a column called `fk_user_id` does not exist in table `table_comments1`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I agree on not mixing the two styles but your conclusion is wrong. There might be a `table_comments1.fk_user_id` column. The error is due to the precedence of `join` versus `,`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
      select  t1.*, t2.* 
      from [table_comments1] t1 inner join users u
      on t1.fk_user_id = u.user_id 
      inner join [table_comments2] t2
      on t2.fk_user_id = u.user_id
```

Answer (score -1):

FYI There are several types of `join`
`t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.fkId` (this is default if `inner` or anything else is ommited) returns records from t1 and t2 where exist matching records in t1 and t2. Old style (`ANSI 89`) looks like this: `...from t1,t2 where t1.id = t2.fkId`
`t1 left join t2 on t1.id = t2.fkId` All records from t1 (including non-matching) and records from t2 where match exists. Non-matching records from t2 are shown as `null`. Old style: `... from t1,t2 where t1.id *= t2.fkId`.
`t1 right join t2 on t1.id = t2.fkId` similar logic as `left join` but all from t2 and matching records from t1 and `null` for non-matching t1. Old style: `...from t1,t2 where t1.id =* t2fkId`.

> `t1 full join t2 on t1.id = t2.fkId` left + right. Everything from t1
>   and t2, `null` for non-matching. Old style: `from t1,t2 where t1.id
>   *=* t2.fkId`.
>   I was wrong. At least at compatibility level 80 `*=*` is not supported by ms sql 2008. I don't have older version to check.

`t1 cross join t2` (no `on` condition) returns `Cartesian Product` of the two tables. For each record from t1 all records from t2. Old style is `... from t1,t2`.
Note that "New Style" was introduced as recently as in 1992 and MS SQL Server 2012 stop supporting "Old Style".

Comment: What does the old style outer join syntax has to do with the question?

Comment: And a `*=*` operator never existed.

Comment: Only the `*=` and `=*` are under deprecation. The `FROM t1,t2` is still supported and still in the recent SQL standard. Hasn't been removed.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I used (at least tested) `*=*` 20 years ago. There is no way to test it with existing servers.  `from t1,t2` is supported but if you try to edit it in query designer it changes to `cross join`.

Comment: I'm curious, which version of SQL Server had `*=*`?

Comment: Probably 7 and 2000. MS Access which uses ansi-89 supported it.

Comment: 2000 definitely not. And it was never in any SQL standard.

Comment: `full join` isn't very popular join type so i can forget. `*=*` as synonym of `full join` is (was) mentioned frequently.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure. But maybe you're looking for something similar to this:

```
select  table_comments1.*,
        table_comments2.*
from    users as u
inner join table_comments1 as c1
on      u.user_id = c1.fk_user_id
inner join table_comments2 as c2
on      u.user_id = c2.fk_user_id
order by isnull(c1.comment_date, c2.comment_date) desc
```